# VB.NET - Memory use of public shared method vs instance method

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory

What is the difference in the way memory is allocated by my application between using a public shared method and a method of an instantiated class?

I have several classes of shared functions which query a database and return domain objects. Altogether these classes contains a lot of methods and I am interested as to whether it would be a better approach in terms of managing resources to use instance members instead.

Comment: The methods don't consume memory at all but the fields do. But the question is: do you _need_ different instances or can these instances  be shared across all threads?

Comment: Short answer "no" as the application is single thread. But I have just been planning a re-write of the data access layer to make use of generic data reading and writing classes. I'll want to access some instance properties of the base class so I won't be able to use shared methods anyway. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is not duplicated once per object instance, only object data is unique per object instance.

There will be no difference in memory usage *for the method code* between public shared or instance methods.